# Find $\lim_{x \to - \infty} \left(\frac{4^{x+2}- 2\cdot3^{-x}}{4^{-x}+2\cdot3^{x+1}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am to find the limit of 
$$\lim_{x \to - \infty} \left(\frac{4^{x+2}- 2\cdot3^{-x}}{4^{-x}+2\cdot3^{x+1}}\right)$$ 
so I used:
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} = \lim_{x \to \infty}f(-x)$$ 
but I just can't solve it to the end.

Comment: my try:$\large\frac{2(8*(12)^x-1)}{1+6*(12)^x}*(\frac{4}{3})^x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \left(\dfrac{4^{x+2}- 2\cdot3^{-x}}{4^{-x}+2\cdot3^{x+1}}\right)
=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \left(\dfrac{3^{-x}(4^{x+2}\cdot3^x- 2)}{3^{-x}(4^{-x}\cdot3^x+2\cdot3^{2x+1})}\right)
=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \left(\dfrac{4^{x+2}\cdot3^x- 2}{(3/4)^x+2\cdot3^{2x+1}}\right)$

The numerator converges to $-2$ while the denominator diverges to $\infty$, and so the limit is $0$.

Comment: I got $0-12/0$, what does that mean?

Comment: @user111410 I'm not sure where you got that expression. The numerator approaches $-2$ since $4^{x+2}\cdot3^x\to0$ as $x\to -\infty$ whereas the denominator diverges to infinity since $(3/4)^x\to \infty$ and $2\cdot3^{2x+1}\to0$ as $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: Yes, okay that's true what you're saying, but my goal is to convert that minus infinity to plus infinity using the formula I listed in the question above, so I can this to the end.

Comment: @user111410 If you want to use $\lim_{x \to -\infty} = \lim_{x \to \infty}f(-x)$, then use it by replacing every instance of $x$ wherever appropriate by $-x$ in what I've written. You'll get the same thing but with the limit as $x\to\infty$. The last expression becomes, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{4^{-x+2}\cdot3^{-x}-2}{(4/3)^x+2\cdot3^{-2x+1}}$ which should be clear is $0$.

Comment: So if the denominator goes to zero and the nominator is -2, then a limit is 0? I always thought if the denominator in a limit is 0, then a solution can be either minus infinity (if a nominator is a negative number) or infinity (if a nominator is a positive number).

Comment: because a fraction with the denominator 0 makes no sense (?) And I really don't know how that works with limits.

Comment: @user111410 The denominator in your problem *doesn't* go to $0$. It diverges to $\infty$ since $(3/4)^x\to\infty$ and $2\cdot3^{2x+1}\to0$ as $x\to-\infty$, so that their sum tends to infinity (or alternatively, $(4/3)^x\to\infty$ and $2\cdot3^{-2x+1}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$). The numerator however is finite and thus, the limit is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Since x goes to minus infinity, the terms $4^{x+2}$ and $3^{x+1}$ are negligible. Then, you have to look at the limit of $-2 * 3^{-x} \over 4^{-x}$, that is to say $- 2 (\frac34)^{-x}$ which is a negative quantity going to zero when $x$ becomes more and more negative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to - \infty} \left(\frac{4^{x+2}- 2\cdot3^{-x}}{4^{-x}+2\cdot3^{x+1}}\right) = \lim\limits_{x \to - \infty} (\frac{-2\cdot 3^{-x}}{4^{-x}})$$

Comment: how did you come to this?

Comment: @Nigel: That $\sim$ should be $=$ here because you're taking the limit.